# How to get size of PCB in Proteus

Tags: proteus

I am new in proteus and I have done a pcb design.I have the following doubts in pcb design using proteus.

1. I need to connect a 100W bulb through the relays. Now the trace style is 
   T30 .Is it sufficient for AC transmission to power a 100W bulb?
2. I don't know how to get the dimension of the pcb I have done. I would like to
   know how to get the length and width of the pcb...? what is the dimension of
   a single tile in the grid...?

[image: this is my pcb design]

Answer (score 4):

There's a mode called Dimension Mode. You can access this mode by clicking the button with a *diagonal two-headed arrow symbol* from the toolbar on the left:

[image]

At this mode, if you draw a line, it will show the length:

[image]

If you want to see the length in metric unit instead of imperial unit, go to View menu then click "Metric". All the dimensions will show in milimeters.

Comment: thank u..can you please tell something about first question

Comment: Assuming the supply voltage for the bulb is 230Vac, so steady state load current will be 100/230=~450mA. Go to [this page](http://circuitcalculator.com/wordpress/2006/01/31/pcb-trace-width-calculator/). Enter 0.45 for Current, 1 for Thickness, 10 for Temp. Rise and 25 for Amb. Temp. For trace length, if you click a trace on Ares, you'll see its length on the status bar at the bottom like "Tagget Route [ ... Length - 0.65in ]" and enter this value for "Trace Length" on the calculator page. You'll see the required trace width under "Results for External Layers in Air:" section.

Comment: i have done this which shows .128mm but how to apply this in proteus there the trace style is shown like T20 T30

Comment: @iqbalpalemad There's a button named "C" (Create) on top-left of the TRACES list (the list where T30, T20 etc. is placed in). Click that button, "Edit Trace Style" window will appear. Type a name like "M.128mm" or whatever you want and type ".128mm" into the Width textbox then click "OK". You'll have a style with a trace width of 0.128mm. Select this new style from the list then redraw the corresponding trace.

Comment: @iqbalpalemad Also please note that the calculated trace width is the "minimum" required value. I personally recommend you to use a larger value (e.g. 0.35mm instead of 0.128mm).

Comment: i am designing a relay module so i need to pass maximum of 5A current is it possible

Comment: @iqbalpalemad If you provide enough trace width then of course it is. Not necessary, but you can use double-sided PCB for such a high current (i.e. power planes on both sides and stitching them with enough number of vias).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50323/discussion-between-iqbalpalemad-and-rohat-kilic).